# Spark: Normalising/Stantardizing test-set using training set statistics

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, pyspark

This is a very common process in Machine Learning.
I have a dataset and I split it into training set and test set.
Since I apply some normalizing and standardization to the training set,
I would like to use the same info of the training set (mean/std/min/max
values of each feature), to apply the normalizing and standardization
to the test set too. Do you know any optimal way to do that?

I am aware of the functions of MinMaxScaler, StandardScaler etc..

Comment: Knowledge of the test set should not be included when you create a model using the training set and then making predictions on the test set.

Comment: It applies because the whole point of the test set is to evaluate how the classifier performs on *new* observations (ones that weren't used to train the classifier). If the trained classifier is used long enough on new data it will likely encounter observations outside the training data min/max. By computing normalization coefficients with the test data included, you prevent that possibility and the test set will then give a less accurate estimate of how the classifier generalizes.

Comment: fair enough. I see your point.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this via a few lines of code on both the training and test set.

On the ***training*** side there are two approaches:

**MultivariateStatisticalSummary**

http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-statistics.html

```
val summary: MultivariateStatisticalSummary = Statistics.colStats(observations)
println(summary.mean) // a dense vector containing the mean value for each column
println(summary.variance) // column-wise variance
println(summary.numNonzeros) // number of nonzeros in each
```

**Using SQL**

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import mean, min, max
In [6]: df.select([mean('uniform'), min('uniform'), max('uniform')]).show()
+------------------+-------------------+------------------+
|      AVG(uniform)|       MIN(uniform)|      MAX(uniform)|
+------------------+-------------------+------------------+
|0.5215336029384192|0.19657711634539565|0.9970412477032209|
+------------------+-------------------+------------------+
```

On the ***testing*** data - you can then manually "normalize the data using the statistics obtained above from the training data.  You can decide in which sense you wish to normalize:  e.g.

**Student's T**

```
     val normalized = testData.map{ m =>
            (m - trainMean) / trainingSampleStddev
      }
```

**Feature Scaling**

```
     val normalized = testData.map{ m =>
            (m - trainMean) / (trainMax - trainMin)
      }
```

There are others: take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalization_(statistics)